# How to make a physical asset an NFT

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, nft, moralis

I am trying to create an NFT but with physical assets, how can I make this work.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical assets"? An NFT is a token on the blockchains that references a JSON file. That JSON file has some standard properties like an URL pointing to a resource like image, movie, etc. You could add additional properties to the JSON file, but for everything off-chain you have manage it your self.

Answer (score 0):

As Ismael has mentioned in the comments, there is a metadata file for each NFT. You could use that metadata JSON file to link to a legal document or include some terms & conditions explaining that the owner of the NFT also owns a certain physical asset (or certain rights to it).